# ¿Cómo puedo implementar AJAX en MVC con URL/controller/action?

Tags: php, ajax, mvc

Tengo un problema al querer realizar una petición `AJAX` para anidar un `SELECT` en un formulario especifico, estoy utilizando `PHP MVC` y en mi `index.php` cargo mis controladores con sus respectivos **métodos(actions)**, resulta que al ejecutar mi función `AJAX`, esta me muestra la información en el **index**, y no mantiene la vista en la cual la ejecuto.

Aquí dejo mi `AJAX`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#idRegion').change(function(){
            $('#idRegion option:selected').each(function(){
                id_region = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?=base_url?>sitio/obtenerProvincias',
                    data: {id_region: id_region},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#idProvincia').html(data.html);  
                    },
                    error: function(xhr,err){
                        console.log("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status+"\n \n responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
public function obtenerProvincias(){

    $id_region = $_POST['id_region'];

    $provincia = new Provincia();
    $provincia->setIdRegion($id_region);
    $provincias = $provincia->getAllByRegion();

    $html = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar Provincia</option>";

    while($pro = $provincias->fetchObject()){
        $html .= "<option value='".$pro->tb_idProvincia."'>".$pro->nombre."</option>";
    }

    echo json_encode($html);
}
```

PD: He ocupado autoload para cargar mis controladores y mi archivo `.htaccess` lo tengo configurado asi:

**HTACCESS:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://URL/MIPROYECTO/error/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Puedes dejar tus archivos de `MVC` por favor

Comment: @VictorAlvarez adjunto el codigo

Comment: seguro es por que la petición que recibes, devuele una vista y no un json, necesitas devolver un json y por cada objeto dentro, renderizar un option del select

Comment: Hola @Felipe estas usando algún framework o tu creaste tu estructura de mvc. Si estas usando alguno por favor colocalo.

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim perdón, me equivoque en mi función obtenerProvincias, ahora editaré el codigo, gracias

Comment: @YoelRodriguez no uso ningún FW, me estoy basando en un MVC desde cero que aprendí en un curso de PHP

Comment: Es importe ver como estas haciendo la ruta de llamado URL para hacer la petición por ajax porque si estoy en lo correcto estas llamando directo a la función y no haces referencia a la controladora y es posible que por esa razón te este mostrando los datos del index. Por favor pon ejemplo de como es que llamas la función por el URL

Comment: @YoelRodriguez gracias por comentar, mi controlador es SitioController y la funcion a la cual llamo es obtenerProvincias, la información que visualizo en el index es la correcta. He intentado crear un archivo obtenerProvincias.php para añadirlo en la URL del AJAX, pero debido a que uso rutas amigables, esta URL me dirige al error que defino en mi ErrorController y no encuentra el archivo

Comment: Pero si estas usando el MVC y rutas amigables lo puedes hacer haciendo que este archivo sea también una controladora. y lo llamarías igual que como llamas a las otras controladoras. Gracias

Comment: @YoelRodriguez claramente mi funcion esta dentro de mi SitioController, pero el resultado en JSON se me muestra en el index... no me recarga el SELECT de donde estoy llamando el AJAX, existe alguna otra forma de anidar el SELECT ?